# Link folder to docker container and populate in runtime

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a dockerized nodejs API where useres can upload images and they get saved while docker is running to `myApp/static/images`. If I deploy a new version to the host and `compose-up -d --build` all images are lost.

How can I **sync** a container folder which gets populated on runtime with the host?

I have tried volumes but it is only copying files from the host to the container at buildtime.

```
version: "3"

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./backend/api
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /etc/images:/static/images
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about why you believe that the image files are not being stored on the host?  Using a volume like this mounts the directory into your container at _runtime_ and any changes that are made to the directory inside the container will be persisted on the host.  Should work fine, I suspect there may be another issue.

Comment: Do you mean the images in `/static/images` are lost, but the images in `/etc/images` exist ?